# How to implement concept like payment gateway and wallet in kivy android and ios

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am researching lot of in **kivy** for **payment** **gateway** and **wallet** like concept and how its feasible, secure and implementation level for **android** and **ios** application. Anyone knows its production level implementation please let me know

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate with any Payment Gateway using documentation given on their Api's documentation page.Google pay and many other have their documentation on How to implement it on any platform (Android,Ios,Web). You can check `https://developers.google.com/pay/india/api/`